# java gwt richtextarea set line-height

Tags: java, gwt, richtextarea

I'm using the RichTextArea in my java gwt project. I was able to set a few parameters of the styling as follows:

```
IFrameElement fe = (IFrameElement) richTextArea.getElement().cast(); 
Style s = fe.getContentDocument().getBody().getStyle(); 
s.setProperty("fontFamily", "Arial Unicode MS,Arial,sans- serif"); 
s.setProperty("fontSize", "small");
```

Everything works fine in FF and Chrome (as usual) but IE is making trouble again, because there the line-height is somehow set to 200% or something or is even making html paragraphs when set a return. 
I tried to set it with

```
  s.setProperty("lineHeight", "...");
```

but that didn't work...

Comment: Please mention the version of IE .

Comment: it happens in version IE8 IE9 didn't test it for IE10

Comment: http://www.webdesignerforum.co.uk/topic/26384-line-height-difference-between-ie-and-ffoperachrome/

Comment: ok but how do I set the 'p {...}' style in my s.setProperty(...)?

Comment: You have to apply conditional css http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/cc2.shtml

Comment: I know but my problem is that I don't know how to apply the css to the richtextarea, because richtextarea.setstylename(..) does not work therefore I extracted the whole thing to IFrameElement and then the Style of the body, which allows me to specify as 's.setProperty(NAME, VALUE)'??

Comment: Why can't you use  richTextArea.setStylePrimaryName(style) ??

Comment: @Atta both shared links are very very old !!!